# Re-formatting data file content using python

Tags: python

I have a large file (example below) with data that I tried re-formatting using python (code below).

File:

```
Segment 30
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Sequuo:              ju0
saeer on werarms23e: 610
//
Segment 30
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Sequuo:              xu0
saeer on werarms23e: 400
//
```

I wanted to have a tab-delimited formatted outputs as below.

Expected output:

```
Sequuo  saeer on werarms23e
ju0 610 
xu0 s400
```

my attempt so far:

```
row=[]
with open("file.txt","r") as infile:
    while True:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith("Sequuo:"):
                line1=line.replace("\t","")
                line1=line.split(":")
                row.append(line1[1].strip())
                #line1=line.replace("\n","\t")
            if line.startswith("saeer on werarms23e:"):
                line1=line.replace("\t","")
                line1=line.split(":")
                row.append(line1[1].strip())
                print row 

            if line.startswith("//"):
                break
        if line=="":
            break
```

Does anyone know how to get this code workin properly?

Thanks

Comment: What output do you get at the moment>?

Comment: With the `print` command you are just printing into console. You should prefer storing the result in another file with `myNewFile = open ("newFile.txt", "w")` and then `myNewFile.write(row)`. Can you show us the output of your code?

Comment: Note that you are assigning `line1` and then instantly reassigning it to something different. Do you mean `line1=line1.split(":")` and so on?

Comment: Your example is not long enough to see a pattern. Which parts always repeat, which parts do repeat, and which parts should be used to group by? Could you provide a longer example, possibly with fantasy names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expected o/p is

```
Sequuo  saeer on werarms23e
ju0 610 
xu0 400
```

Then try this code:

```
import sys
row=[]
with open("file.txt","r") as infile:
    while True:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith("Sequuo:"):
                line1=line.replace("\t","")
                line1=line.split(":")
                row.append(line1[1].strip())
                #line1=line.replace("\n","\t")
            if line.startswith("saeer on werarms23e:"):
                line1=line.replace("\t","")
                line1=line.split(":")
                row.append(line1[1].strip())


            if line.startswith("//"):
                break
        if line=="\n":
            break

print ('Sequuo  saeer on werarms23e')

count = 0
for i in row:
    count +=1
    sys.stdout.write (i + '\t')
    if not count%2:
        print
```